# Is there a flaw in the burnination process for blatantly off-topic tags that have the same meaning in all common contexts?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

An essential initial requirement in our [burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/6471538) is that a tag must meet *all* of the following criteria to qualify for advancing to the next step:

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

I was thinking of how one hypothetically could break the process (as engineers are wont to do), and came up with the following scenario:

I am asking a question about adding a new, custom date notification type to a calendar widget to cover liturgical fast days. In addition to tagging my question with the appropriate language, framework, and possibly widget tags, I also tag my question [russian-orthodox-church](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/russian-orthodox-church). Nobody bothers to remove the tag, so by the end of the year, we have dozens of questions with the tag that are really programming questions that are vaguely inspired by religion but don't really require any religious knowledge to solve. Someone hops onto Meta to request a burnination, correctly observing that the tag doesn't describe the contents of the questions, isn't even on-topic, and adds no meaningful information to posts. Another person rebuts that [russian-orthodox-church](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/russian-orthodox-church) *does*, in fact, mean the same thing in all common contexts.

Is there a solution to this conundrum? Do we apply a little human discretion and disregard criterion #4 above if the tag is blatantly off-topic? Do we follow the letter of the rule and let the tag stay? Have I completely misunderstood the standard interpretation of the burnination criteria?

Other hypothetical tags that this might apply to could include [maslow-hierarchy-of-needs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maslow-hierarchy-of-needs), [krebs-cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/krebs-cycle), [atmosphere-of-venus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atmosphere-of-venus), [uk-parliament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uk-parliament), or [great-pyramid-of-giza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/great-pyramid-of-giza).

Comment: "*Is there a solution to this conundrum?*" yes. And it's simple - don't blindly follow rules. In practice, I don't think we expect ALL of the criterial to fail because that would be, as you've shown with your example, silly.

Comment: I can ask, "What type of shingles are best used for fixing roof on a Russian orthodox church" and it wouldn't mean the same thing. So I think the criteria still holds.

Answer (score 5):

After those criteria, there's:

> In any case, the ultimate criterion for burnination is whether the tag is actually causing harm

Is the tag causing harm? No. So the rest of the question is moot.

"blatantly off-topic" and "helping categorize questions" are not the same.

Comment: This seems to be the right answer– the burn criteria are guiding points that exist to help discern whether a tag causes harm or not. Also, in the question's hypothetical case, if the [russian-orthodox-church] tag started _attracting_ off-topic questions, then it could be construed to _be causing harm_, thus ending the dilemma, and being eligible for burn.

Comment: That's exactly the point of burnination as I understand it: for removing nonsensical categories, and those that attract offtopic questions.